# Use a variable inside a render of react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I need to use the url from a json and render it on the screen, using React Native and axios.
I'm getting the url with this:

```
teste() {

        api.get('photos').then(

            function imagens(response) {
                var i = 1;           
                for (i; i < 2; i++) {
                    urlDaImagem = response.data[i].url
                    console.log('em cima->' + urlDaImagem)
                }
                return urlDaImagem
            })

    }
```

I need to put that "urlDaImagem" inside of a Image component.
The entire code:

```
    import React from 'react';

import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Image,
    StatusBar
} from 'react-native';

import api from '../api';

var urlDaImagem

class PaginaPrincipal extends React.Component {

    teste() {

        api.get('photos').then(

            function imagens(response) {
                var i = 1;           
                for (i; i < 2; i++) {
                    urlDaImagem = response.data[i].url
                    console.log('em cima->' + urlDaImagem)
                }
                return urlDaImagem
            })

    }

    render() {   

        return (
        
            <>
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
                        <View style={styles.sideBySideImages}>
                            <Image style={styles.imagens} source={{ uri: urlDaImagem }} />

                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imagens: {
        width: "45%",
        height: 183,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginStart: "3%",
        marginEnd: "1%"
    },
    sideBySideImages: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }
});

export default PaginaPrincipal;
```

Comment: how about to use state for this case ?

Comment: can yout recomend me how? on this case

Comment: try this https://www.javatpoint.com/react-native-state

Comment: basically all you have to do add urlDaImagem  in the state object with initial value, then inside imagens function you can use setstate to update the value of urlDaImagem.

Comment: When will the teste() function called? whether on click of any touchable or on componentDidMount, in both case you have to use state, save the updated url in state and in render() method you can use it

Answer (score 0):

you can use state in your case, read about it from here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

and I updated your code try to test it, and see the best life cycle to call teste function and this should do the trick

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Image,
    StatusBar
} from 'react-native';

import api from '../api';


class PaginaPrincipal extends React.Component {
    state={
           urlDaImagem:""
          }
    teste() {

        api.get('photos').then(

            function imagens(response) {
                var i = 1;
                let urlDaImagem;
                for (i; i < 2; i++) {
                    urlDaImagem = response.data[i].url
                    console.log('em cima->' + urlDaImagem)
                }
                this.setState({urlDaImagem})
            })

    }

    render() {   

        return (
        
            <>
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
{ this.state.urlDaImagem && 
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
                        <View style={styles.sideBySideImages}>
                           <Image style={styles.imagens} source={{ uri: this.state.urlDaImagem }} /> 

                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </SafeAreaView>
}
            </>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imagens: {
        width: "45%",
        height: 183,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginStart: "3%",
        marginEnd: "1%"
    },
    sideBySideImages: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }
});

export default PaginaPrincipal;
```

Comment: It's giving me the following error:
source.uri should not be an empty string

Comment: add a ternary if statement to render the image as soon as the uri is fetched from the server

Comment: try it and let me know if it is worked, and if you find the answer useful kindly up voted or marked as resolved

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, if you could help me out I'd be very very glad

Comment: Got the follwing error now:
 Error: Text strings must be rendered within 
a <Text> component.

Comment: try the latest update, you should read more on JS first and React, before moving to react native

Comment: Can you still help me?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, sorry

Answer (score 0):

To load data from API it is better to use `useEffect` hook (React native supports it):
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update

Also, React to work properly should control the state of your components. You have to declare state by `useState` hook, for example. Global vars won't work without tricks)

```
function PaginaPrincipal(props) {
  const [urlDaImagem, setUrlDaImagem] = useState();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      api.get('photos').then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        const [{ url }] = data;
        setUrlDaImagem(url);
      });
    },
    [] // Effect does not depend on any props
  );
  return (
    <>
      ...
      <Image style={styles.imagens} source={{ uri: urlDaImagem }} />
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```